# C-Execvp() always fails

Tags: c, exec

i'm trying to make a shell in c and currently trying the ls command but the child always returns that `execvp` couldn't work. here is the function.first i get the path i'm in and the command i get from `stdin` using exec that is why i remove the newline after that i duplicate the command and using `strtok`(delimiter is " ") i put all the arguments in an array for `execv` and the "close it" with a null terminating string after that i print the elements of the array which give correct output ex(ls -l give ls "newline" -l) and then i print the path who also gives correctl output (/home/usr_name/Desktop). But the `execv` never works and it returns the `fprintf`

```
void ls(char* path,char* cmd){
    int pid,elements,l,i=0;;
    l=strlen(cmd);
    if(cmd[l-1]=='\n'){
        cmd[l-1]='\0';
    }
    char* ccmd=strdup(cmd);         
    char* t_cmd;
    char* w_cmd[1024];
    t_cmd=strtok(ccmd,DELIM);
    while(t_cmd!=NULL){
        w_cmd[i]=t_cmd;
        t_cmd=strtok(NULL,DELIM);
        i++;
    }
    w_cmd[i]='\0';
    elements=i;
    for(i=0;i<elements;i++){
        printf("%s\n",w_cmd[i] );
    }
    printf("%s\n",path);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        execvp(path,w_cmd);
        fprintf(stderr, "Child process could not do execvp\n");
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Child exited\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: If a system call fails, it will always set [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Check that for what the problem is. You can use [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string from the error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it says permission denied

Comment: Also you are mix up the term null *pointer* and null *character*. The first, a null pointer, is represented by the `NULL` macro in C. A null character, which is the terminator for strings in C, is the character literal `'\0'`. The argument array you pass to the `execv` functions should be terminated by a null *pointer, i.e. `NULL`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude changed `w_cmd[i]=NULL;` from '/0' but it still doesnt work and i dotn think thats why i get permission denied but thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `path` is equal to `"/home/usr_name/Desktop"` (with your real user name of course)?

Then that is the problem. If you [read an `exec` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) it will tell you that the first argument is the *command* that you should execute.

So to execute `ls -l` with `execvp` you should do e.g.

```
char *w_cmd[] = { "ls", "-l", NULL };
execvp(w_cmd[0], w_cmd);
```

Comment: thank you i changed the first argument to "ls" and it worked without changing the w_cmd though

Comment: @noname95 Since the command should normally be the same as the first argument (`w_cmd[0]`) I updated my answer to use it instead.